# What is a good way to check the sort order on a Rails index page in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Clicking on a column header is supposed to reload the page and sort the table via params.

What is a good way to test the order of the rows using RSpec?

Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

make your that you have at least two entries in your database and then only thing you need is

```
result = YourTable.all.sort_by(&:YOUR_COLUMN)    
result.first.YOUR_COLUMN > result.second.YOUR_COLUMN
```